# What should be my SQL data type to pass my json payload?

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I'm building an API in Anypoint Studio - Mule 4 that will push the payload to a SQL table. However, i can not retrieve my payload because the data type i set in sql is not correct. I've tried (decimal, BIGINT, int, and nvarchar)

Error Message:

> The conversion from UNKNOWN to BIGINT is unsupported.

my payload:

```json
{
    "reporting_user": null,
    "mission_type": null,
    "id": 171950377,
    "campaign_id": 3928802,
    "place_id": 19831979,
    "user_id": 236636,
    "state": "completed",
    "created_at": "2023-03-28T11:52:01.501-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2023-03-28T11:52:34.154-04:00",
    "expires_at": "2023-04-07T11:52:00.000-04:00",
    "completed_at": "2023-03-28T11:52:33.000-04:00",
    "coordinates1": 27.78919982910156,
    "coordinates2": -97.66523709893443,
    "started_at": "2023-03-28T11:52:00.000-04:00",
    "location_timestamp": null,
    "location_accuracy": null,
    "completed_coordinates1": 27.78919982910156,
    "completed_coordinates2": -97.66522805987546,
    "my_gsc_completed": null,
    "distance_to_place": "0.0572254913380641"
}
```

i need help defining the data types for coordinates and completed_coordinates to fix my payload issue.

Comment: What does the above question have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: @ThomA i'm pushing the payload into a sql table

Comment: But what about the question is about SQL Server? That error isn't a SQL Server error, so where is it coming from and why is that relevant to SQL Server?

Comment: @ThomA - I'm building an api in anypoint studio that will push the payload to a sql table. The data types in the table i created have to be correct. This is a data type issue that i can not figure out.

Comment: So you are getting the error when you `INSERT` the data into the table? Then include the DDL of your table and the code you are using the `INSERT` that JSON into your table.

Comment: @ThomA I get an error in Anypoint Studio when attempting to insert the payload into the table. Error message: The conversion from UNKNOWN to BIGINT is unsupported.

Comment: So the problem is in Anypoint studio, not SQL Server..? The error isn't a SQL Server error, so the problem appears to be before you get to SQL Server.

Comment: @ThomA Table: create table dbo.GSC_MissionResponses
(
reporting_user nvarchar (255),
mission_type nvarchar (255),
id int,
campaign_id int,
place_id int,
user_id int,
state nvarchar (255),
created_at datetime,
updated_at datetime,
expires_at datetime,
completed_at datetime,
coordinates decimal,
started_at datetime,
location_timestamp nvarchar (255),
location_accuracy nvarchar (255),
completed_coordinates decimal (255),
my_gsc_completed nvarchar (255),
distance_to_place decimal
)

Comment: @ThomA there error is happening because the datatype set for payload field is incorrect:   "coordinates": [
        25.12345672910156,
        -97.66523709893123

Comment: Are you splitting that JSON array prior to trying to insert it? You can't insert `25.12345672910156, -97.66523709893123` into a `decimal`. Also `decimal` would be interpreted as a `decimal(18,0)`, which means that you're going to lose a lot of accuracy.

Comment: @ThomA I have not split the json array. thank you for your help

Comment: The issue is during Mule runtime execution of the application, not in Studio which is just the IDE.

Comment: @ThomA - what datatype would you recommend for  -97.66523709893123

Comment: I doubt very much that SQL Server allowed you to create a column of data type `decimal(255)`. Instead of pasting chunks of code and/or DDL in comments please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76739142/edit) your question to include the real table definition.